# Simple proof that $a$ is coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a$ divides $x^n-1$ and $x^m-1$, then $a$ is coprime with $x$.

I think this should be easy but I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: What is the significance of $m,n$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson they are positive integers

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $n\ge 1$. Let $d$ be a common divisor of  $a$ and $x$.

(i) Since $a$ divides $x^n-1$, it follows that $d$ divides $x^n-1$.

(ii) Since $d$ divides $x$, it follows that $d$ divides $x^n$.

From (i) and (ii), we conclude that $d$ divides $x^n-(x^n-1)$, and therefore $d$ divides $1$.

We have shown that any common divisor $d$ of $a$ and $x$ divides $1$. So $a$ and $x$ cannot have a common divisor greater than $1$, and therefore $a$ and $x$ are relatively prime.

Comment: that's not what I asked

Comment: I have shown that already from $a$ divides $x^n-1$ we can conclude that $a$ and $x$ are relatively prime. There was no need to use the additional information that $a$ divides $x^m-1$.  So the question you asked has been answered. But perhaps that question was not what you intended to ask.

Comment: Nicolas Sorry mate, my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a matter fact, I fiddled around with the problem and got this:

Let $m>n$  then if $a$ divides $x^m-1$ and $x^n-1$, it divides $(x^m-1)-(x^n-1) = x^m-x^n = x^n(x^{m-n} - 1)$ Now if $a$ divides $x^n$ then clearly they're not coprime. Let's assume it divides $x^{m-n}-1$ instead, then it must divide $(x^{m-n}-1)-(x^n-1)=x^{m-n}-x^n = x^n(x^{m-2n}-1)$ Now again, if it doesn't divide $x^n$ then it must divide the other factor, and we can keep going on like this till $m-kn<0$ and at that point $a$ must divide $x^n$ which means it is not coprime with $x$.

Combining this with André Nicolas's proof, I guess it means that **$x^m-1$ and $x^n-1$ are relatively prime so the hypothesis isn't even true** **. No such $a$ exists.**